# Core Data EXC_BAD_ACCESS when assigning to a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory-management

I am trying to save a value for Core Data Entity like this:

```
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSError *error = nil;

for (NSDictionary *dic in controlTypeResponse.DataDic) {
    ControlType *controlType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ControlType" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];

    controlType.controlTypeID = [[dic valueForKey:@"ControlTypeID"] integerValue];
    controlType.controlTypeName = [dic valueForKey:@"ControlTypeName"];
}

[coreDataStack.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

But when assign `controlTypeID`, app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. The interesting thing is the memory address field in error detail `(code=1, address=0x2)` changes depending on `[[dic valueForKey:@"ControlTypeID"] integerValue]`'s value(For example the value is 2 in this case).

Any idea about why this happens? I searched Core Data Documentation and concurrency related problems on SO but my problem does not seem related to those problems.

Comment: What type have you set in your model for your attribute `controlTypeID`?

Comment: @andrewbuilder Integer 32

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain you're creating a type mismatch here...

So in your Core Data model, do you have the Class Codegen set to "Class Definition" or "Manual/None"?

If you've set it to "Manual/None", you'll be able to inspect your `NSManagedObject` subclass header file for your entity `ControlType`.

Maybe the declaration for the attribute looks something like this?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * controlTypeID;
```

If not, what type is it set to?

If you've set it to "Class Definition", you'll not be able to inspect the `NSManagedObject` subclass for your entity `ControlType`, however I understand that Core Data defaults all Integers (Integer 16, 32, 64) as type `NSNumber`.

So either way, for your call to set `controlType.controlTypeID` to work, you'll need to convert your attribute `controlTypeID`'s number value to a type that Core Data can translate into your model (and thereby persist to the persistent store).

If my guess is correct, this may work...

```
controlType.controlTypeID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[dic valueForKey:@"ControlTypeID"]]
```

If it does not, maybe I have misunderstood... let me know.